# several GML to one layer

Tags: openlayers, gml

Is there any way to draw several GML polygon to one Vector Layer?
I have several KML files with polygon coordinates.
I draw to the map like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < telepHatarArray.length; i++){
  var telep_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GML", {
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
      url: "telephatarok/telepules_" + telepHatarArray[i].kshkod + ".kml",
      format: new OpenLayers.Format.GML()
    }), 
    style: {
      fillColor: "#F6EA9D",
      strokeColor: "#000000",
      fillOpacity: 0.2
    },
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()]
  });

  map.addLayer(telep_layer);
}
```

But with this it generates every polygon to a new layer.

After drawing this, I draw points with Layer.Text.

```
var newlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Text(
    "Települések", 
    { 
      location:"./"+forras
    }
);

map.addLayer(newlayer);
```

'forras' is the file source. When it gives more than 50 polygons, the popup boxes open under the polygons. I tried setting the layerindex of the newlayer, but it won't help.

Thanks for the advices. And sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Silly me! I just add the GML polygons to one file, and that solved my problem.